# FTP account without linux user

Tags: 12.04, ftp, vsftpd, pure-ftpd

Is it possible to create a FTP user account without a user creation in linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some ftp servers can handle *virtual users*, ex. vsftpd and pureftpd.